Why i get random number on X?
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float X, Y;

    printf("%f\n", X);
    printf("%f\n", Y);
}

Soo why X is not 0 like Y ?
Is there any reason why, or only i get that "bug" ?

Both are uninitialized. Reading them is undefined behavior. That means anything can happen (Y being 0 is also not guaranteed).

In C programming, if you declare variables but don't initialize them, they end up holding random, meaningless values. This happens because such variables grab whatever leftover data was already sitting in their assigned memory spots when they were declared. Local variables are stored in an area called the stack, which often retains bits of data from earlier activities unless it's specifically cleaned out or replaced.
Edit: note that the variable should have non static lifetime.

Welcome to SO. You should add that this only applies to variables with non-static .lifetime

Yo thanx, i should have been more comprehensive

Re “if you declare variables but don't initialize them, they end up holding random, meaningless values”: Per the C standard uninitialized objects do not “hold” any value at all; they are indeterminate, which means they may appear to have a different value each time they are read. Also, the values that appear are not specified to be random or meaningless. They are uncontrolled by the C standard, but they are unlikely to be random. They are more likely to be consequences of other things in the C implementation, which are neither random nor meaningless.

Re “such variables grab whatever leftover data was already sitting in their assigned memory spots when they were declared”: As the objects are indeterminate, the values that appear for them are not necessarily what is in memory. A value may be taken from memory on one use, from a register on another, and from a different register on another.

Re “Local variables are stored in an area called the stack”: This is a common way of implementing automatic objects, but it is not specified by the C standard, and it is not always used. General C implementations that do use a stack nonetheless often use processor registers for automatic objects, so there may be no stack space assigned for an object.
